# CakePHP 3: HTMLHelper:url missing

Tags: php, cakephp, html-helper, cakephp-3.0

I am currently upgrading an application to CakePHP 3. In CakePHP 2 I was using HTMLHelper::url to generate links to controllers/actions for buttons and so on.

Something like this:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left form-signin" action="<?php echo $this->HTML->url(array(
    "controller" => "users",
    "action" => "login")); ?>" method="post">
```

As you can see I am using `$this->HTML->url()` to generate links to my controller/actions. In CakePHP 3 HTMLHelper::url() is missing. Neither the documentation nor the migration guide mentions it. Is there another way to generate links in Cake 3?

Thanks!
Alex

Comment: use $this->Url->build(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login'));

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the migration guide:
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#view-helper

> Helper::url() is now available as Cake\View\Helper\UrlHelper::build().

Comment: Thanks! I did not see that in the guide. P.S.: Ich mag deinen Blog :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Router::url()`](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#generating-urls) method to get action url. So just change your line as follows:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left form-signin" action="<?php echo Router::url(array("controller" => "users", "action" => "login")); ?>" method="post">
```

By the way, why don't you use [FormHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html) to generate your form?

Comment: This would lack the additional entity encoding that the helper applied.

Comment: I am a noob with HTML and PHP :-( I haven't found a way to generate Boostrap compatible forms with the FormHelper. It was always very confusing thus I switched to do it on my own. I hope to get better with all of this and do it the proper way...in the future.

Answer (score 0):

For creating links you can use **link** method of the cakephp

```
Cake\View\Helper\HtmlHelper::link(string $title, mixed $url = null, array $options =[])
```

Try this for your above mentioned code

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left form-signin" action="<?php echo $this->HTML->link(array(
    "controller" => "users",
    "action" => "login")); ?>" method="post">
```

Comment: -1 How can anyone vote this up? This is total nonsense, `HtmlHelper::link()` creates a HTML `<a>` element, not just a URL! Also the not properly cased property will fail on case-sensitive filesystems as it will look for `HTMLHelper.php`.